# How to show data without calling an api on back press?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

Suppose `ActivityA` calls an API to load the data, after that clicking on one content, I move to `ActivityB`. Now When I press BackPress the `ActivtyB`, I do not want to call API again and load the data. I want it should show the old data without calling an API again.

How can I achieve this? Should I call finish() on `onBackPress()` or there is some another way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the Activity B finishes , Activity A will again get the focus of UI . Activity's A onResume method will be called . Make sure not to write the fetch API logic in onResume and onPause methods and you will have old data from Activity A.
Alternatively you can use

[Loaders and Syncers](https://medium.com/google-developers/making-loading-data-on-android-lifecycle-aware-897e12760832)

Answer (score 1):

Either to save data in Local SQlite after calling API first time, and call same API after refreshing .